# rails application user signup form multiple type of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, registration

I've some doubts about design of a user signup form in Rails for multiple type of users.

Users are either regular_user, admin_user (I like active_admin ), or a vendor.
Now regular users need only name and an email address to signup while vendor needs name,email and few additional inputs like credit-card,date, phone#, etc.

So the questions are,
Should I create two separate models for regular user and a vendor? 
Do they need two separate login forms too? How about managing common resources (user can see all vendors [only name,contact#] and vice-versa read-only).
While active_admin uses devise and has it's own admin_users table.

What if in future I need to use some kind of authorization scheme using let's say 'cancan'?  Ryanb's railscasts describesthat all admin,moderators,authors are in one table with an additional column to differentiate.

What is the best practice in similar situation while designing a web application?
Just looking for some guidance not code.

Thanks, and I really appreciate any input.

Atarangp

Comment: What approach did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a user table with flags for admin and vendor.

The -very- general answer is do not to duplicate code or data.
So you should try to avoid multiple login forms,
and multiple name/email columns.
There's usually a way to accomplish this.

To consider further: will you handle users who want to enter their phone number, 
or later also become a vendor or administrator?

Edit:

> how do you create the dynamic view for user and vendor with additional input fields?
>   and how do you use html forms and all the tags?

I think you should start with the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html),
and a [demo movie by Ryan Bates](http://media.rubyonrails.org/video/rails_blog_2.mov).
(The movie used to be [on the screencasts page](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts), but there seems to be a typo.)

The guides have a section on ["views"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), and [here you can learn about forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Comment: Brian, Thanks. My current use case has this simple requirement, although that could change in future as you pointed out. Having one table definitely keeps things simple but how do you create the dynamic view for user and vendor with additional input fields? I'm not very knowledgable on html forms and all the tags and how do you use them with Rails?